# Spellcheck disable with CSS not HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to disable spellchecking in Chrome/Safari using CSS. In HTML `spellcheck="false"` works but I want to do this in a way that will affect all input fields. I tried `input{spellcheck: disabled}` but this didn't work.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Is there a chance to use JavaScript? Otherwise I wouldn't do it. Don't judge the looks over the usability.

Comment: Some people are saying "not CSS" but I completely support this desire. If I would like spellcheck enabled but for my own reasons not visible in some areas of say a contenteditable div then I should be able "hide it". In my context it is about display rather than turn the internal checking on or off.

Answer (score 14):

use jQuery. Something like:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("input[type='text'], textarea").attr('spellcheck',false);
});
```

This should search for all textbox's and teatarea's on the page and add the attribute `spellcheck="false"` to them.

Comment: Note : disabling spellcheck on Safari (version 9.1.1 in my case) donnot remove red spellchecks underline wave

Answer (score 6):

This does not belong to the realm of CSS (which is optional presentational suggestions). It is not about stylistic features of rendering data but about processing data interactively.

On browsers that support “spell checking” (which may involve grammar and style checks), the HTML attribute `spellcheck` or the corresponding IDL (DOM) attribute, settable in JavaScript, is effective.

In practice, those browsers tend to have “spelling checking” enabled by default for textareas only, and as textareas normally contain human language texts, turning it off does not sound useful. It is in any case user-controllable (the user can switch it off or select language).

Comment: It might be sensible to disable spell-checking on all textareas if your site’s users write a lot of URLs, file paths, and code in them – for instance, if you have a bug tracking site. It’s annoying to type a variable name and have it marked as misspelled, but that is unavoidable when spell-checking mixed code and English.

Comment: Another use-case, if you site only uses inputs for names and emails.

As names and emails often get lots of false-positives.