# textarea immitation is not working well. any replacements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this html and css: http://jsfiddle.net/b7rDL/6/

HTML:

```
<div class="text-block" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">Some Text</div>
```

css:

```
.text-block {
    resize: none;
    font-size:40px;
    border: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    min-width: 30px;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This code allows me to write text with no width limit or height limit. It displays no scroll bar and it grows with the text. Those are basically the features I need.

1. How can I convert this to regular textarea that will act the same? I want this to work on browser that doesn't implemented "contenteditable". Therefore I want to replace the div with textarea or other basiv element. How can I do it? (I don't mind using JavaScript).
2. How can I disable the spellchecker? `spellcheck=false` doesn't work. In the example, when I focus on the text box, I get that buggy red line. I am using Firefox.
3. How can I get rid of the border when I am focused? - SOLVED

**I don't mind using JavaScript to solve those issues.**

Any answer for those questions will help me.

Thanks

UPDATES:
@Oylex helped me with 3

Comment: Down vote because you know the answer or because you didn't understand it?? People that doesn't explain why they down vote has no dignity!

Comment: Some observations. First, there is no native CSS way to build an auto-growing `textarea`, so you will require JavaScript. Second, `spellcheck="false"` is definitely the right way to disable spellchecking on a field—what browser are you seeing this on? Can you add a jsFiddle and some specifics?

Comment: @Naor - can you explain #1?

Comment: @JordanGray: I updated my question and relate to your comment.

Comment: @PankitKapadia: I updated the question. I wrote: "This code allows me to write text with no width limit or height limit. It displays no scroll bar and it grows with the text. Those are basically the features I need. ".

Comment: @Naor, something like this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AHw8r/1/) I found? Note: The contents aren't actually saved.

Comment: @arttronics - this is similar to your jsFiddle example. [http://jsfiddle.net/GeJkU/](http://jsfiddle.net/GeJkU/)

Comment: @arttronics: About your first and second examples: When I press edit I get textarea with scroll. he jQuery plugin also scroll. I need the width to determined by the text.

Comment: Why do you need this functionality? I'm just curious.

Comment: @QuentinEngles: Do you know the text box that Photoshop and other imae editors have? Draggable, sortable float text box. This is what I am trying to do with textarea.

Comment: @Naor: You mostly want it to grow w/h as text is entered, but you'd like it to be supported in most browsers. There are not many options that I know of that will do that other than measuring the scroll of a textarea. Maybe a hidden div that accepts the input so you can get it's growth value and apply it to the textarea. It's a tough one.

Comment: @QuentinEngles: This is why I am looking for some help :)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to #1 and/or #2?

Comment: @JSuar: Not something that works perfect. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having trouble figuring out the bounds of the `textarea`'s content, so with this approach I'm copying the content of the `textarea` into a similarly styled `p` element, which is set to `float: left;` and then resizing the `textarea` based on the size of the `p`. This handles both width and height.

I've tested on Mac 10.8.1 FF 18.0, Safari 6.0, Chrome 25.0.1362.0 canary, iOS Safari 6.0.1 and iOS Simulator 5.1 (272.21). I don't have a PC or IE handy.

http://jsfiddle.net/b7rDL/34/

HTML

```
<textarea id="tx" class="text-block" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
<p id="dupe" class="text-block"></p>
```

CSS

```
.text-block {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    resize: none;
    font-size:14px;
    border: none;
    line-height: 1;
    min-width: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: pre;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

#dupe {
    float: left;
    display: none;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

<sub>I added a background and border so I could see what's going on.</sub>

JavaScript

```
// no `var` so they are global and easier to work
// with in the inspector when using jsFiddle

$tx = $('#tx');
$dupe = $('#dupe');
lineH = Number($tx.css('line-height').replace('px',''));

update();

$tx.on('keydown', function() {
    setTimeout(update, 0);
});
$tx.on('propertychange input keyup change', update);

function update() {
    $dupe.text($tx.val());
    $tx.css({
        width: $dupe.width() + 7,
        height: $dupe.height() + lineH
    });
}

// not sure if this is needed, leaving it because
// I don't have many browsers to test on
 $tx.on('scroll', function() {
     tx.scrollLeft = 0;
     tx.scrollTop = 0;
 });
```

I'm adding extra space on the right and at the bottom because it seems to perform more consistently that way. Also, in the HTML, the `wrap="off"` is necessary for the version of Firefox, I'm using.

I got some good tips from [this blog post](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript).

Comment: In my testing I was trying to avoid the wrap="off" property. Why do you need it? How can we avoid it?

Comment: @Naor Hm, now that I'm testing it again it doesn't seem to make a difference. I must've forgotten to test without it after making some other changes. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Why did you do: $dupe.width() + 7? Where come from the 7?
If I remove it then any new line appears late.

Comment: @Naor New lines of text appear late or the extra space on the bottom appears late? The 7 is arbitrary, I put it there to compensate for bad responsiveness, but after reading that blogpost most of the issues were resolved. I kept the 7 in because I haven't been able to test it on that many browsers, so I'm not totally sure it will be fine without it. The only time I've noticed the new line (extra space, only) appearing late is when there is no character on the bottom, the last character is the new line character. I haven't worked that out yet. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Take this situation for example: go to this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b7rDL/35/ and type letter by letter: "rtyuio" . Then you see the "o" letter is invisible. There are more inconsistencies like this. If I could figure what cause this then I will be able to prevent it.

Comment: @Naor I see what you mean. I see this only in FF. I was able to stop it by either adding 7 to the width (`width: $dupe.width() + 7` but maybe some smaller number will work) or by setting `wrap="off"`.

Comment: $dupe.text($tx.val() + "|");
       $tx.css({
        width: $dupe.width() + 7,
        height: $dupe.height()
       }); This will make bit help for extra space under the text

Comment: white-space `pre` yeah, that's smart

Comment: @dmi3y You're suggesting it's better to have a textarea that collapses white-space? Why is `white-space: pre` bad?

Comment: @tiffon, I am telling it is good, no sarcazm, it is really smart, I do not think about it before, I am going to use it

Comment: @dmi3y Oh, got it. Sorry about the mix-up!

Answer (score 9):

### #1

Working fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/d9H9w/11/ (tested in IE8, Chrome and Firefox)

What you need is to set the width and height attributes as a user is typing within a text box.

#### Height

This is pretty straightforward:

1. Get the content of the textarea
2. Match for newline characters
3. Set the height to total number of newline characters(plus one for the first line and 1.5 for wiggle room) in em's.

Setting the height in em's makes this font-size agnostic, so it'll work with multiple font-sizes.

```
function getNewlines(){
    // get the value(text) of the textarea
    var content = textEl.value;

    //use regex to find all the newline characters
    var newLines = content.match(/\n/g);

    // use the count of newlines(+1 for the first line + 1 for a buffer)
    // to set the height of the textarea.
    textEl.style.height = ((newLines && newLines.length || 0)+2.5)+'em';
};
```

#### Width

This is fairly easy, too, with one gotcha.

1. Get the content of the textarea
2. Split on newline characters to get an array consisting of lines of the textarea
3. Sort to get the longest line
4. Set the width to the length of the longest string in em's, *multiplied by about .6(emRatio in my code)*, plus 2 ems for buffer space.

That last part is the kicker.  The 'em' measurement is supposed to be a square representing the width and height that a single character takes up.  This doesn't take kerning into account, so the height of a char is usually accurate, but the width is dependent on the chars around it.  So, by guess and check, I figured that .6 em is about the average width of a character after kerning.  .6 is pretty close, so I add 2 ems to the width for a bit of buffer space.

```
var emRatio = .6;
function longestLine(){
    // get the value(text) of the textarea
    var content = textEl.value;

    // split on newline's. this creates an array, where each item in
    // the array is the text of one line
    var a = content.split('\n');

    // use a sorting function to order the items in the array:
    // longest string to shortest string
    a.sort(function(a,b){return b.length - a.length});

    // use the longest string * the emRatio to set the width
    // Due to kerning, the letters aren't ever really 1em x 1em
    // So I'm multiplying by an approximate ratio here (guess and check)
    textEl.style.width = (a[0].length * emRatio + 2)+ 'em';
};
```

#### Existing problems with this implementation

- To support resizing during long-held key presses, an onkeydown handler has to be included as well(this is not optimal for all cases that don't include long key presses)

All things considered, I think this fits what you need.

**EDITS**

Instead of having emRatio be .7, I changed it to .6 and added a buffer of 2 ems to the width. This addresses both issues @Naor mentioned in his comments.

I've updated the fiddle link and the **Width** section to reflect the changes.

Comment: @naor THIS should be the answer. It works flawlessly. Come on OP - credit this guy!

Comment: @Jonathan F: Thanks for the answer! There is a bug :) When typing the first 3 letters the letter appear on the second line (you have to delete all text in your jsfiddle and thenn start typing). I am using FF.

Comment: Another thing, for each space you type (" ") the textarea getting more and more larger. The width thing is suffer from a small calculation problem. Is there any way to improve this?

Comment: @Naor -- Both issues you mention derive from approximating average kerning to .7.  Bringing that ratio down to .6 makes the average more accurate, and cuts down on whitespace from extending the line too much.  Adding a constant of 2ems width after the calculation addresses the issue regarding the first few characters typed in an empty textarea. Both of these changes are reflected in my answer.

Comment: There is also a little jump on 'enter'.  Instead of adding 2 em's to the height, add 2.5 and this is fixed.

Comment: @JonathanF: Does the -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline; and -webkit-appearance: textarea; styles are required??

Comment: @JonathanF: In this component I enable font resizing by dragging the bottom-right corner. The problem is that the emRatio is different for different font sizes. I couldn't manage to find a way to calculate emRatio depending on the font-size. If you have better idea, it might help. Big thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT 0**

**Request #1 Update**

Working Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/7aeU2/

JQuery

```
$(function() {
    //  changes mouse cursor when highlighting loawer right of box
    $("textarea").mousemove(function(e) {
        var myPos = $(this).offset();
        myPos.bottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        myPos.right = $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth();

        if (myPos.bottom > e.pageY && e.pageY > myPos.bottom - 16 && myPos.right > e.pageX && e.pageX > myPos.right - 16) {
            $(this).css({ cursor: "nw-resize" });
        }
        else {
            $(this).css({ cursor: "" });
        }
    })
    //  the following simple make the textbox "Auto-Expand" as it is typed in
    .keyup(function(e) {
        //  the following will help the text expand as typing takes place
        while($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"))) {
            $(this).height($(this).height()+1);
        };
    });
});​
```

**Request #2 Update**

Also, here's a good explanation of why you can't outright disable spell check.

> This does not belong to the realm of CSS (which is optional
>   presentational suggestions). It is not about stylistic features of
>   rendering data but about processing data interactively.
>
> On browsers that support “spell checking” (which may involve grammar
>   and style checks), the HTML attribute `spellcheck` or the corresponding
>   IDL (DOM) attribute, settable in JavaScript, is effective.
>
> In practice, those browsers tend to have “spelling checking” enabled
>   by default for textareas only, and as textareas normally contain human
>   language texts, turning it off does not sound useful. It is in any
>   case user-controllable (the user can switch it off or select
>   language).

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/9209791/1085891

---

**Request #1**

1. **Simple Solution** is pretty straight forward.

   Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/b7rDL/12/

   JQuery

   ```
   $("#Solution0").keyup(function(e) {   
       while($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight) {
           $(this).width($(this).width()+50);
       };
   });
   ```

   HTML

   ```
   <textarea id="Solution0" rows="1" style="height: 1.2em;"></textarea>
   ```
2. **Fancier solution** that will require some updating if you want the
   width, rather than the height, to expand. Still, it's pretty nice.

   - http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/HrnHb/
   - https://github.com/ultimatedelman/autogrow
3. **Other solutions** - I know these all expand height. Let me know if you need width implementation of one of the below solutions.

   - http://bgrins.github.com/ExpandingTextareas/
   - http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/textarea-expander/index.html
   - http://code.google.com/p/xautoresize-jquery/downloads/list
   - http://www.impressivewebs.com/textarea-auto-resize/
   - http://www.technoreply.com/autogrow-textarea-plugin-3-0/

**Request #2**

`spellcheck="true"` should work as described in the [Mozilla docs: Controlling spell checking in HTML forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms). It works for me in my first simple example running in Firefox 13.0.1. What version are you running?

Comment: @JStar: Thanks for your answer. I've seen most of the links you put. I need the exact width rather then height. I prefer not to use solutions like autogrowth that uses clone divs because I need to add 30 Text Boxes like this on one html file (I prefer the simplest structure possible).

Comment: @JStar: I also try to support Enter key to go to the next line. The user should be able to write a text like text editor and if he wants to go to the next line he should be able to use enter.

Comment: I updated your first jsFiddle to now include an overflow: hidden which hides the annoying jumping... http://jsfiddle.net/7aeU2/

Comment: @JSuar: I need textarea to resize itself, both width and height, as the user type in.

Answer (score 3):

for #3, the css option you are looking for is: `outline: none;`

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

**Request #2**

Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b7rDL/19/)

```
<body spellcheck="false">
<div class="text-block" contenteditable="true">    
Some Text SpellCheck</div>
```

Hi Naor,  The only problem with this thing is it will disable the ***spellcheck*** for all the elements in the `<body>` tag. If it doesn't matter you then you can go with it.

Your question is really interesting and challenging really liked it. I hope this may help you..!!

Comment: I can wrap the contenteditable div with another div with spellcheck="false"! Thanks for your answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Best efficient way which was worked for me while I did something very close in the past was creating hidden out of flow `div` with the same exactly styles as the textarea has. And than setting out the timeout to update its html source based on information from textarea. This sounds bit scary but yet, after some testing and playing around nothing was better, that was already suggested, so just my variant.

http://jsfiddle.net/f2gAD/16/

and jQuery based script:

```
var textarea = $('textarea'),
    textBlock = $('div.text-block'),
    interval, value, freq = 10,
    doTextAreaAdjust = function(){
       textarea.css({
          height: textBlock.outerHeight(),
          width: textBlock.outerWidth()
       });
    };
doTextAreaAdjust();
textarea
.focus(function(){
    interval = window.setInterval(
        function() {
          value = textarea.val().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '[rnnr]');
          value = value.replace(/</gm, '||'); // break html tags
          value = value.replace(/\[rnnr\]/gm, '<br>');
          value = value + '|'; // or <span>|</span> for better pixel perfect
          textBlock.html(value);
          doTextAreaAdjust();
        }, freq
    );console.log(interval);
})
.blur(function(){
    window.clearInterval(interval);
});
​
```

For performance wise did it as self starting/stopping timeout on focus/blur, though here is yet some workaround is required. While testing in Chrome noted that interval not properly stopped if you made blur by clicking on another tab. So probably replacement for self calling function into the `setTimeout` will be better.

It works more or less fine in IE 7-8 which suppose the main targets but still some text jumps time to time occur, while for others it is okay, but guess you will use editable feature for modern browsers. Would recommend use modernizer for its detection.

Comment: This behaves inconsistent. Fill the first row and then the line will break. Then delete all text and start to write again. Now the line will not break.

Answer (score -1):

Working here
http://jsfiddle.net/H2GSx/

Code here:
HTML:

```
<div style="overflow: scroll; width: 200px; height: 100px;">
    <div class="text-block" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">Some Text</div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.text-block {
    resize: none;
    font-size:40px;
    border: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    min-width: 30px;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
​
```

Comment: I am trying to replace the contenteditable div with something more common! All your examples are using contenteditable divs. Haven't you read the question?